# Ошибка: несоответствие типов со знаком и без знака

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Vigenere
{
public:
  string key;

  Vigenere(string key)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < key.size(); ++i)
    {
      if(key[i] >= 'A' && key[i] <= 'Z')
        this->key += key[i];
      else if(key[i] >= 'a' && key[i] <= 'z')
        this->key += key[i] + 'A' - 'a';
    }
  }

  string encrypt(string text)
  {
    string out;

    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < text.length(); ++i)
    {
      char c = text[i];

      if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
        c += 'A' - 'a';
      else if(c < 'A' || c > 'Z')
        continue;

      out += (c + key[j] - 2*'A') % 26 + 'A'; 
      j = (j + 1) % key.length();
    }

    return out;
  }

  string decrypt(string text)
  {
    string out;

    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < text.length(); ++i)
    {
      char c = text[i];

      if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
        c += 'A' - 'a';
      else if(c < 'A' || c > 'Z')
        continue;

      out += (c - key[j] + 26) % 26 + 'A'; 
      j = (j + 1) % key.length();
    }

    return out;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Vigenere cipher("VIGENERE");

  string original = "test";
  string encrypted = cipher.encrypt(original);
  string decrypted = cipher.decrypt(encrypted);

  cout << original << endl;
  cout << "Encrypted: " << encrypted << endl;
  cout << "Decrypted: " << decrypted << endl;
}
```

Когда компилирую этот код выдаёт ошибки:

```
(12): warning C4018: <: несоответствие типов со знаком и без знака
(25): warning C4018: <: несоответствие типов со знаком и без знака
(45): warning C4018: <: несоответствие типов со знаком и без знака
```

Как можно решить?

Comment: Вообще, это не ошибка. Это предупреждение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать не `int`, а `size_t` - тип, который возвращает `.size()`...

Нет, конечно, остается еще вариант

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4018)
```

и вы не получите соответствующих сообщений вообще :)